# Meteor.js: New article. Notification visible to all users

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I would like to notification new article visible to all users. In the scheme of data "Notifications" added value boolean "read: false", the "false" start the display of the notification of the creation of a new article.

```
Notifications.insert({
       userId: post.userId,
      postId: post._id,
       read: false
    });
```

User after the launch of the link to the article contained in the notification changes the value of the object "read: true," causing that notification is not visible to him, and for all users.

How to make to notification visible to other users if one of them changes the value of "read: true".

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about your modelling and how you want to keep read state in your document. If you want to keep the read state for each users, you need to save / modify (when read) accordingly. How you keep this information is up to you. For example you can keep the readers list in the notification document and remove the user when he reads the notification. Or another alternative would be that you have a separate collection to keep user's notifications list, from which you remove notification item when read.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have an idea to link the data schema data Meteor.users id articles and values "true / false" for notifications